# Android systrace or atrace python parser to parse the results

Tags: android, linux, perf, systrace, ftrace

any one know how to parse the systrace or atrace files like following and get the timestaps of any process using python or any other language?

```html
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
          atrace-1724  [000] d..3 14186.680000: sched_switch: prev_comm=atrace prev_pid=1724 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [000] d.h7 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=tfm_b6bcf800 pid=1714 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=000
          <idle>-0     [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 next_pid=1714 next_prio=35
    tfm_b6bcf800-1714  [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 prev_pid=1714 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D|W ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systrace output has two parts, the trace data and a fixed blob of code that acts as the viewer.  The systrace python script concatenates the two.  The viewer is written in javascript; you can [find the source tree here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-trace/+/lollipop-release/trace-viewer/).

Comment: Thanks fadden, how to run this script? 
how can i pass my recorded systrace html file as parameter?